# Loop resets variable

Tags: ruby, loops

I am encountering the following unexpected behavior while running the following loop:

```
outside_var = 'myString'
loop do
  inside_var ||= outside_var
  result = SomeCalculation.do_something(inside_var)
  inside_var = result[:new_inside_var_value]
end
```

Now, on the first iteration `inside_var` gets set to `outside_var`, which is the expected behavior. Just before the next iteration I set `inside_var` to something else (depending on the result I got from the calculation inside the loop). This assignment works (printing `inside_var` at the very bottom of the loop confirms that). On the next iteration, however, `inside` var goes back to the original state, which is something I didn't anticipate. Why is it doing that and how can I set this variable inside this loop?

I am running Ruby 2.6.5 with Rails 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a new iteration inside the loop, you are going to reset everything. I suggest you to modify the var outside the loop to preserve the value inside. Something like this:

```rb
result_var = 'myString' # value on the first iteration
loop do
  result = SomeCalculation.do_something(result_var)
  result_var = result[:new_inside_var_value] # at the end of the first iteration you are already overriding this value
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping issue. `inside_var` is scoped to the block. One might check the binding, it changes.

```rb
outside_var = 'myString'
2.times do
  puts "INSIDE 1: #{defined?(inside_var).nil?} → #{binding}"
  inside_var ||= outside_var
  puts "INSIDE 2: #{inside_var}"
end
#⇒ INSIDE 1: true → #<Binding:0x000055a3936ee0b0>
#  INSIDE 2: myString
#  INSIDE 1: true → #<Binding:0x000055a3936edc50>
#  INSIDE 2: myString
```

That said, every time the execution enters the block, the binding is reset, that’s why one should not expect the variables from another scope (with another binding) to exist.